# Set Today View as default on Lock screen in iPhone

Tags: iphone, lockscreen

Is it possible to make Today View as the default on the iPhone Lock screen?

Currently I need to swipe right on the Lock Screen to see the Today View screen (security is not an issue because Today View is accessible to anyone without logging into the iPhone).

I want the Today View screen to be the default on the Lock Screen when the iPhone is locked.

I am using an iPhone 7.

Answer (score 1):

No. As of this writing, it is not possible to set Today View as the default view in lock screen.